# Capture navigation to a custom protocol from WebView in Windows Store App

Tags: webview, windows-store-apps, custom-protocol

Is there a way to capture the click on a hyperlink with href (eg: myapp://xyz) in any of the Webview's navigating event for a Windows Store (8.1) App? I know this can be achieved using window.external.notify in the html. This feature was missing in wp7 and was later added in wp8 
Is this not allowed in windows 8.1 apps or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

By WebView in windows phone 8, I presume it to be a WebBrowser control. 
Apparently there is no direct way i could find to get a hyperlink click. Because all the internal rdirects, hyperlinks and similar navigations not initiated by user interactions have the same kind of pattern that the link click has. So there is no apparent direct way to segregate them. (Unless of course you handle some ui events like a tap on the browser etc. which i do not think is a wise way of going at it.)

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Deochakke for your reply. Yes, I was referring to the WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 8. Seems to be a serious flaw in the webview control for windows 8.1. Hopefully there will be some update from MS which will include the feature. Are you aware of any updates coming?

Comment: Here is an msdn page that talks about web view control in 8.1. Hope it helps :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx

Well, from the available straight forward events in it, it does not seem possible to trap an event of tapping on an html link. But nothing can be said unless we actually start working on it and try to figure out any indirect methods to trap the event.

Hope my answer and this link in the comment takes you in the right direction. Do accept the answer or vote up if it helped :) 
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 you can use the "UnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified" event on the WebView.  Make sure to set the event args Handled to true so the Windows dialog doesn't pop up.